# @Autowired private MessageConverter simpleMessageConverter; throwing exception

Tags: spring-jms

I have a requirement to upgrade my service from 2.6.6 to 3.0.0 but below code is resulting in an exception in SB 3.0.0 but the same code is working fine in SB 2.6.6

@Autowired private MessageConverter simpleMessageConverter;'

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Note: <spring-amqp.version>3.0.0</spring-amqp.version> is being used in spring boot 3.0.0

I tried creating a bean manually, but still it is not working fine

org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter